# Ghostscript converting PS to PNG

Tags: png, ghostscript, postscript

I am using two different systems:

**A:**   SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)  VERSION = 11  PATCHLEVEL = 2 with GPL Ghostscript 8.62

**B:**   SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)  VERSION = 12  PATCHLEVEL = 5 with GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3
I convert the same postscript file jjtest3.ps to png using the same command:

/usr/bin/gs -I/wws/daten/var -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -dUseFastColor=true -r120x120 -sOutputFile=output.png jjtest3.ps  -c quit;

An example off  output.png from system A is in the file sles11_2.png (see the link below).

An example off  output.png from system B is in the file sles12_5.png (see the link below).

The problem is, that the png created on system B is not in that quality as from system A. There are missing some thin lines – see the examples.
The GS option -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 yields better result, but I don’t want to use it, because the output device is an e-ink display, which uses only 100% black, white and red colors. So the result png should have only 2 colors (red, white).
**My question is: Which Ghostscript options under the GS version 9.53 would yield the same (or better result) as under the version 8.62? Or any other ideas?**
I think a downgrade to the older GS version on SLES12 system is not really a good option for the future.

[sles11_2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2qmi.png)[sles12_5.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrj9q.png)

The content of the Postscript file jjtest3.ps is:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%CreationDate: 20201229 16:26:53
%%Pages: 1
%%Orientation: Portrait
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 240 180
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog

/lib_logo_nr_00639 {
% BEGIN_LOGO 00639  ***** Logo ESL Jetzt in Aktion *****
/X 284 def /Y 170 def % Breite und Hoehe des gesamten Feldes
/weiss { 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 setcmykcolor } def
/rot { 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 setcmykcolor } def
/s {stroke} def /sl {setlinewidth } def
/c {curveto} def /l {lineto} def /m {moveto} def /f {fill} def
/HG_rot { 153.0 2.9 m 207.9 23.8 l 211.2 24.9 215.4 27.6 215.4 34.5 c
215.4 158.6 l 215.4 158.6 215.4 169.9 204.0 169.9 c 79.9 169.9 l
79.9 169.9 68.5 169.9 68.5 158.6 c 68.5 34.5 l 68.5 34.5 68.5 27.0 74.6 24.2 c
78.8 22.6 l 134.4 1.4 l 134.4 1.4 137.4 0.0 141.7 0.0 c
146.0 0.0 153.0 2.9 153.0 2.9 c 153.0 2.9 l } def
/Innen { 199.7 55.5 m 199.7 97.8 l 193.4 97.8 l 193.4 87.2 l
193.4 84.0 193.6 78.2 193.6 75.3 c 192.8 78.5 191.2 84.0 190.1 87.5 c
186.7 97.8 l 180.6 97.8 l 180.6 55.5 l 186.9 55.5 l 186.9 69.2 l
186.9 72.9 186.8 78.7 186.7 81.7 c 187.5 78.6 189.2 72.7 190.5 68.5 c
194.6 55.5 l 199.7 55.5 l  170.2 76.5 m 170.2 63.7 169.5 61.0 167.3 61.0 c
165.2 61.0 164.4 63.8 164.4 76.8 c 164.4 89.6 165.0 92.3 167.2 92.3 c
169.4 92.3 170.2 89.5 170.2 76.5 c 170.2 76.5 l  177.2 76.8 m
177.2 91.2 174.8 98.5 167.3 98.5 c 159.8 98.5 157.4 91.3 157.4 76.5 c
157.4 61.9 159.7 54.8 167.2 54.8 c 174.8 54.8 177.2 62.0 177.2 76.8 c
177.2 76.8 l  153.9 55.5 m 153.9 97.8 l 147.1 97.8 l 147.1 55.5 l 153.9 55.5 l 
144.6 91.5 m 144.6 97.8 l 126.3 97.8 l 126.3 91.5 l 132.0 91.5 l 132.0 55.5 l
138.8 55.5 l 138.8 91.5 l 144.6 91.5 l  126.2 55.5 m 120.0 82.1 l 126.0 97.8 l
119.1 97.8 l 116.5 90.3 l 115.6 87.9 114.4 83.9 113.8 81.3 c
113.9 83.9 113.9 86.9 113.9 90.0 c 113.9 97.8 l 107.2 97.8 l 107.2 55.5 l
113.9 55.5 l 113.9 71.8 l 115.0 74.6 l 119.1 55.5 l 126.2 55.5 l  96.3 70.9 m
92.5 70.9 l 93.4 78.6 l 93.8 81.6 94.2 85.1 94.3 88.5 c
94.5 85.1 94.9 81.7 95.3 78.7 c 96.3 70.9 l  104.9 55.5 m 98.1 97.8 l
90.9 97.8 l 84.2 55.5 l 90.9 55.5 l 92.0 64.8 l 96.9 64.8 l 98.1 55.5 l
104.9 55.5 l 198.6 101.8 m 198.6 138.3 l 195.4 138.3 l 195.4 121.4 l
195.4 117.8 195.5 114.1 195.6 111.9 c 194.9 114.9 193.6 119.1 192.3 123.1 c
187.4 138.3 l 184.1 138.3 l 184.1 101.8 l 187.2 101.8 l 187.2 120.5 l
187.2 124.1 187.2 127.8 187.1 130.0 c 187.7 126.9 189.0 122.8 190.3 118.8 c
195.9 101.8 l 198.6 101.8 l  178.4 101.8 m 178.4 138.3 l 175.1 138.3 l
175.1 101.8 l 178.4 101.8 l  162.4 135.2 m 162.4 138.3 l 148.5 138.3 l
148.5 135.2 l 153.8 135.2 l 153.8 101.8 l 157.1 101.8 l 157.1 135.2 l
162.4 135.2 l  146.0 101.8 m 146.0 105.0 l 137.1 105.0 l 146.0 135.3 l
146.0 138.3 l 134.5 138.3 l 134.5 135.1 l 142.6 135.1 l 133.7 104.8 l
133.7 101.8 l 146.0 101.8 l  131.8 135.2 m 131.8 138.3 l 117.9 138.3 l
117.9 135.2 l 123.2 135.2 l 123.2 101.8 l 126.5 101.8 l 126.5 135.2 l
131.8 135.2 l  115.8 101.8 m 115.8 105.1 l 107.0 105.1 l 107.0 119.7 l
112.8 119.7 l 112.8 122.9 l 107.0 122.9 l 107.0 135.0 l 115.3 135.0 l
115.3 138.3 l 103.7 138.3 l 103.7 101.8 l 115.8 101.8 l 98.3 110.3 m
98.3 138.3 l 95.0 138.3 l 95.0 110.4 l 95.0 106.2 93.9 104.5 92.1 104.5 c
90.3 104.5 89.2 106.2 88.6 111.0 c 85.3 110.4 l
86.1 104.5 87.9 101.3 92.0 101.3 c 95.8 101.3 98.3 104.3 98.3 110.3 c
98.3 110.3 l 204.6 38.5 m 79.3 38.5 l 79.3 40.6 l 204.6 40.6 l 204.6 38.5 l
204.6 34.5 m 79.3 34.5 l 79.3 36.6 l 204.6 36.6 l 204.6 34.5 l 204.6 157.1 m
79.3 157.1 l 79.3 159.2 l 204.6 159.2 l 204.6 157.1 l 204.6 153.1 m 79.3 153.1 l
79.3 155.2 l 204.6 155.2 l 204.6 153.1 l 204.6 38.5 m 79.3 38.5 l 79.3 40.6 l
204.6 40.6 l 204.6 38.5 l } def
/Rahmen { 152.6 3.8 m 207.6 24.7 l 207.6 24.7 l
209.1 25.2 210.8 26.1 212.2 27.6 c 213.5 29.1 214.4 31.3 214.4 34.5 c
214.4 158.6 l 214.4 158.6 l 214.4 158.9 214.3 169.0 204.0 169.0 c
204.0 169.0 l 79.9 169.0 l 79.6 169.0 69.5 168.9 69.5 158.6 c
69.5 34.5 l 69.5 34.5 l 69.5 34.2 69.6 27.6 75.0 25.0 c 75.0 25.0 l 79.1 23.5 l
79.1 23.5 l 134.8 2.3 l 134.8 2.3 l 134.8 2.3 137.6 0.9 141.7 0.9 c
145.8 0.9 152.6 3.8 152.6 3.8 c 152.6 3.8 l 208.2 22.9 m 153.3 2.1 l 153.3 2.1 l
152.8 1.8 146.0 -0.9 141.7 -0.9 c 137.5 -0.9 134.4 0.4 134.0 0.5 c
78.5 21.7 l 78.4 21.7 l 74.2 23.3 l 74.2 23.3 l 67.6 26.4 67.6 34.4 67.6 34.4 c
67.6 34.5 l 67.6 158.6 l 67.6 170.9 79.8 170.9 79.9 170.9 c
79.9 170.9 l 204.0 170.9 l 204.0 170.9 l 216.3 170.9 216.3 158.7 216.3 158.6 c
216.3 158.6 l 216.3 34.5 l 216.3 30.8 215.2 28.2 213.6 26.4 c
212.0 24.5 210.0 23.5 208.2 22.9 c } def gsave 1 sl weiss Rahmen s rot HG_rot f
weiss Innen f grestore
% END_LOGO
} def
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup

%%BeginFeature: *InputSlot Tray1
<< /InputAttributes << /Priority [0] >> >> setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
%%BeginFeature: *PageSize E8
<< /Policies << /PageSize 2 >> /PageSize [240 180] >> setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
%%BeginFeature: *Trimbox Offset
%%<< /PDFXTrimBoxToMediaBoxOffset [0 0 0 0] >> setdistillerparams
%%EndFeature
%%EndSetup
%%Page: 1 1
newpath
0 0 moveto 
0 180 lineto
240 180 lineto
240 0 lineto
closepath
gsave
1 0 0 setrgbcolor
fill
grestore

/g_kf_xabs 0 def  /g_kf_yabs 90.72 def 
 g_kf_xabs g_kf_yabs moveto currentpoint translate .4836 .4836 scale 0 rotate 
lib_logo_nr_00639
showpage
```